# Convertir Double[] a String

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee

Tengo el siguiente código en Python el cuál quiero implementar en Java pero tengo un problema a la hora de representar el array de elementos de tipo `double` a `String`.

He probado haciendo un 'casteo' de la forma `return (String) this.coordinates();`, invocando el método `.toString()` de la forma `return this.coordinates().toString();` e invocando el método `.valueOf` de la forma `return String.valueOf(this.coordinates());` pero ninguno me retorna la salida esperada
De igual modo tengo un error a la hora de retornar el tipo `boolean false` pues si comparo dos puntos que sean iguales me devuelve `false` en vez del correspondiente `true`

Input:

(10.0, 5.0);

Output:

(10.0, 5.0);

**Código en Python**

```
class Point2D:

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y


    def coordinates(self):

        return (self.__x, self.__y)

    def __eq__(self, other):

        if type(other) == Point2D:
            return self.coordinates() == other.coordinates()
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):

        return str(self.coordinates())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    point1 = Point2D(10.0, 5.0)
    point2 = Point2D(12.0, 5.0)
    print(str(point1), str(point2), point1 == point2)
```

**Código en Java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Point2D {

    protected double x, y;

    public Point2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double[] coordinates() {
        double[] result = {this.x, this.y};
        return result;
    }

    @Override   
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        Point2D iterable = (Point2D)other; 
        if (other instanceof Point2D) {
           return this.coordinates() == iterable.coordinates();
        } else {
            return false;
          }
    }

    @Override   
    public String toString() {
        return this.coordinates().toString();
        //return String.valueOf(this.coordinates());
       // return (String) this.coordinates();

    }
```

Comment: Para comparar los contenidos del objeto, solo usa el método: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(double[],%20double[])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador `==` es para comparar datos primitivos o referencias. Si quieres comparar el contenido del arreglo, tienes que iterarlo y comparar sus elementos, de lo contrario solo si la referencia es la **misma** `==` retornará `true`.

Por otra parte el metodo `toString()` de un arreglo no hace una conversion a string de su contenido. Para eso podrías utilizar [Arrays.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double[]))

Answer (score 1):

En este caso, al comparar dos instancias de la misma clase y al ser solo dos datos, yo compararía los valores simplemente. Algo así:

```java
mport java.util.Arrays;

public class Point2D {

    private double x, y;

    public Point2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public double[] coordinates() {
        double[] result = {this.x, this.y}; // No hacen falta los this.
        return result;

    }

    @Override   
    public boolean equals(Object other) {

        if (other instanceof Point2D) {
            Point2D iterable = (Point2D)other; 
           if (x == iterable.x && y == iterable.y) {
               return true;
           } else {
               return false;
           }
        } else {
            return false;
          }
    }

    @Override   
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%f %f", x, y);

    }
}
```

Comment: Si empleo ese código se produciría un error puesto que, al evaluar la instrucción `other.x` u `other.y` lanzará una excepción tipo:  `x cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: No lo he probado, pero no creo que te dé ningún error. Aunque ya me pica la curiosidad, voy a probarlo.

Comment: Pues me equivoqué en la declaración de la variable other... Te pongo de nuevo el código.